# Measure text width without rendering it in the textview?

Tags: android, textview

I need to measure the width of a spanned text before deciding to render it in a textview.

I'm currently using `Layout.getDesiredWidth()` but I get slightly inaccurate results, and worse, it's very slow.

What could be the better (faster and more accurate) alternative?

I'm actually thinking of the way textviews reflow its text. Doesn't it need to measure its contents before it renders them?

Comment: Does `Paint.measureText(txt)` help?

Comment: Are you extending `ReplacementSpan`?

Comment: do you want each paragraph to be lay-out in a single line? why do you need the width for?